# Web automation with R code

Tags: r, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to get information from a url by making search on it, under R with any package?

I would like to make a loop for searching different code on the url and click on a precise place to write the code and to download document. A software does that, Actionaz, but I don't manage to make a loop with different code executing one after one.

Thank's, 
Xavier

Comment: It is possible. There are several useful packages: `RSelenium`, `rvest`, `splashr`, `Rcrawling`, `httr`....

Comment: I found all what i wanted in the package "webdriver" ! Thanks for the track with Rselenium (not avalable on the cran) but it work like web driver ! Good !

Answer (score 0):

I found on forum "RSelenium" package like you suggest but it is not avalable on the CRAN ? I will see the over packages. I would add some informations of what i would do to know if it's realy possible on not  ^^ :

1/open the url : http://hydro.eaufrance.fr/selection.php?consulte=rechercher

2/clic on the search region (precise point on screen)

3/type a name of station the first : "K0120020"

4/Search it on the website by clic on buton search

5/Select the station found with a clic

6/an over clic to get access to the data

7/Select the year on a dawn drop menu

8/Export data by clic on buton export

Comment: it is not on cran but you can install it from github Rselenium page

Comment: Thank's Mislav, i will try ;)